# KeyError: 0 when attempting to create a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, keyerror

as the title says, I'm trying to create a plot from some data I extracted partially from a csv file, by creating a Pandas dataframe. Essentially, I have 13 csv files, and I have imported them and extracted the maximum value from a specific column in each of csv files. I then put these values into a list. I am hoping to use this list as the y-values for the plot. The 13 x-values were simply manually written (they were measured outside of the software that produced the csv data). The list of y-values is given the name "max_intensities" and the list of x-values are given the name "conc_arr" where conc_arr is a numpy array.

Upon trying to do this, I get an error "KeyError: 0" with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\Computing Labs\Computing Lab Session 3\BeerLambert.py", line 113, in <module>
    intensities_arr=np.array(max_intensities)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1005, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

Here is my code

```
#importing packages
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd

#%% White Light
df_0=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\0g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_0=df_0.max()
print(max_I_0)

df_1=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\0.54g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_1=df_1.max()
print(max_I_1)

df_2=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\1.02g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_2=df_2.max()
print(max_I_2)

df_3=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\1.57g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_3=df_3.max()
print(max_I_3)

df_4=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\2.03g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_4=df_4.max()
print(max_I_4)

df_5=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\2.71g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_5=df_5.max()
print(max_I_5)

df_6=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\3.15g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_6=df_6.max()
print(max_I_6)

df_7=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\3.85g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_7=df_7.max()
print(max_I_7)

df_8=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\4.30g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_8=df_8.max()
print(max_I_8)

df_9=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\4.82g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_9=df_9.max()
print(max_I_9)

df_10=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\5.32g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_10=df_10.max()
print(max_I_10)

df_11=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\5.85g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_11=df_11.max()
print(max_I_11)

df_12=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\BeerLambert\6.41g food-colouring.csv',header=None,usecols=[1],skiprows=33)
max_I_12=df_12.max()
print(max_I_12)
#%%
max_intensities=[max_I_0,max_I_1,max_I_2,max_I_3,max_I_4,max_I_5,max_I_6,max_I_7,max_I_8,max_I_9,max_I_10,max_I_11,max_I_12]
print(max_intensities)


#%%
conc_white=[0,0.001358559,0.002565715,0.003945814,0.005096789,0.006800161,0.007900479,0.009653236,0.010772892,0.012072636,0.013317313,0.014649905,0.016031012]
conc_arr=np.array(conc_white)
print(conc_arr)
#%%
plt.plot(conc_arr,max_intensities)
```

I think the plotting is somewhat irrelevant to the issue but I have kept it in anyway. Upon reading the internet, I believe the issue has something to do with the use of a dataframe (even though the list I created was just made up of single results of the dataframe).

I am very new to python so apologies if this is rather simple.

Thanks in advance,
Sid

**Edit 1**
I isolated the max_intensities and its print into its own code cell as follows:

```
#%%
max_intensities=[max_I_0,max_I_1,max_I_2,max_I_3,max_I_4,max_I_5,max_I_6,max_I_7,max_I_8,max_I_9,max_I_10,max_I_11,max_I_12]
print(max_intensities)
#%%
```

where max_I_0, max_I_1, ... , max_I_12 are from the the code cell entitled White Light at the start of the post.

Upon running the max_intensities and its print, I get this response:

```
runcell(4, 'C:/Users/Sidharth/Documents/Computing Labs/Computing Lab Session 3/BeerLambert.py')
[1    0.69145
dtype: float64, 1    0.667281
dtype: float64, 1    0.631413
dtype: float64, 1    0.603292
dtype: float64, 1    0.572469
dtype: float64, 1    0.542753
dtype: float64, 1    0.512
dtype: float64, 1    0.4904
dtype: float64, 1    0.50323
dtype: float64, 1    0.488207
dtype: float64, 1    0.450364
dtype: float64, 1    0.442091
dtype: float64, 1    0.419718
dtype: float64]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: first you can use `print()` to see what you have in variables which makes problem - `print( max_intensities )` - because it seems you have empty data and it can't get even `data[0]`

Comment: @furas I've isolated the max_intensities and its print (Edit 1). It shows that the data I want is being printed, specifically the 13 decimals.